# Why is "verse" used in "La cantante, cuya carrera se vio afectada por las problemas de adicción..."?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

If *"verse"* means "to see oneself", "to find oneself", "to look", "to see each other" why is it used in the following sentence?

*La cantante, cuya carrera se vio afectada por los problemas de adicción, fue hallada muerta.*

Comment: Verse afectado can mean ‘to suffer’, so the sentence could mean eg ‘...career suffered because of addition problems’

Answer (score 6):

*Verse* followed by a state is a synonym for something being (or finding itself) in that state. This is covered by definition #17 of *[ver](https://dle.rae.es/?id=baOo6Gz)* in the Dictionary of the RAE. What follows the verb can be an adjective or any other complement that shows a state, place or situation. Often you can treat it as a synonym for the periphrastic passive voice.

- *Su carrera se vio afectada.* = "Her career was affected."
- *Ella se vio abandonada por sus amigos.* = "She was [or: found herself] abandoned by her friends."
- *Cuando se vio en problemas no supo qué hacer.* = "When she was [or: found herself] in trouble, she didn't know what to do."